# http request with ec2 aws server is not working

Tags: http, nginx, amazon-ec2, nestjs, web-deployment

i have an EC2 instance on AWS that i have deployed a MERN stack on, i have defined nginx as follows:

```
server {
    #listen       80;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  yourdomain.com;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/client/server_logs/host.access.log main;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    location /api/ {
        add_header X-debug-message innnnnnnnnnnnnn;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }

    location /admin-dashboard {
        root /home/ubuntu;
        index index.html;
        add_header X-uri "$uri";
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    } 

    location / {
        root /home/ubuntu/client/deploy;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        add_header X-uri "$uri";
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    }
  
 
 
    location = /49x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    server_tokens off;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

}
```

And i have attached the security groups as an screenshots.
when i tried to fetch data with this url http://clikjo.com/api/ , using browser or postman it works perfectly, but when i try it using javascript with fetch or Axios it fails with this error:
[TypeError: Network request failed]

can anybody solve my problem?

i have tried to:

- change my security groups
- add headers, specify mode , fetch options , ... etc

Answer (score 0):

If you load a page in your browser using HTTPS, the browser will refuse to load any resources over HTTP. As you've tried, changing the API URL to have HTTPS instead of HTTP typically resolves this issue. However, your API must not allow for HTTPS connections. Because of this, you must either force HTTP on the main page or request that they allow HTTPS connections.

Note on this: The request will still work if you go to the API URL instead of attempting to load it with AJAX. This is because the browser is not loading a resource from within a secured page, instead it's loading an insecure page and it's accepting that. In order for it to be available through AJAX, though, the protocols should match.

You are getting CORS error.
You need to fix it on server-side with additional header.

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
```

Comment: i already have this header in my node server though i does'nt work with http requests, neverthelses this same server was deployed on heroku and it was working